# Micro frontend using module federation - not able to use shared bootstrap css module

Tags: reactjs, shared-libraries, gatsby, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I am using `module-federation` and trying to create a `Micro Fronetend` demo in which I have a Gatsby project ( let's say it as Client ) which is exposing these 2 components:

1. A `HelloWorld` component with `HelloWorld.module.css` & `HelloWorld.css`.
2. A `Header` component which is a Bootstrap 5.3.2 header example.

here is the config for Client:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    // 'gatsby-plugin-sass',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-federation',
      options: {
        ssr: process.env.MF_SSR !== 'false',
        federationConfig: {
          name: 'remote',
          exposes: {
            // Exported components
            './HelloWorld': './src/components/HelloWorld',
            './Header': './src/components/Header',
          },
          shared: {
            bootstrap: { singleton: true, eager: true, import: "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" }
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

It is exporting the components which are under `exposes` object and I am able to import them in another Gatsby & in a ReactJS project and it is also exposing `Bootstrap` as shared dependency.
Here is a snippet of `remoteEntry.js` file:

```
switch(name) {
/******/                case "default": {
/******/                    register("@gatsbyjs/reach-router", "2.0.1", function() { return Promise.all([__webpack_require__.e("framework"), __webpack_require__.e("node_modules_gatsby_dist_internal-plugins_bundle-optimisations_polyfills_object-assign_js-nod-07400b")]).then(function() { return function() { return __webpack_require__(/*! ./node_modules/@gatsbyjs/reach-router/dist/index.modern.mjs */ "./node_modules/@gatsbyjs/reach-router/dist/index.modern.mjs"); }; }); });
/******/                    register("bootstrap", "5.3.2", function() { return Promise.all([__webpack_require__.e("styles-node_modules_bootstrap_dist_css_bootstrap_min_css"), __webpack_require__.e("node_modules_bootstrap_dist_css_bootstrap_min_css")]).then(function() { return function() { return __webpack_require__(/*! ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css */ "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"); }; }); });
/******/                    register("react-dom", "18.2.0", function() { return Promise.all([__webpack_require__.e("framework"), __webpack_require__.e("webpack_sharing_consume_default_react_react")]).then(function() { return function() { return __webpack_require__(/*! ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js */ "./node_modules/react-dom/index.js"); }; }); });
```

In this file I can see `Bootstrap 5.3.2` is exposed but somehow I am not able to import and apply it on my imported `Header` component, neither in Gatsby nor in ReactJS project.

Please help me to use this shared exported dependency preferably in ReactJS project.

Thanks in advance.

**P.S.:** If you want to see some code snippet which I haven't added here then please let me know, I will add it.